# Java Beans to test a class

Tags: java, javabeans, java.util.scanner

I was given a class DrivingTestM.java to test with a 2 classes I wrote. Here are the classes I wrote. When i run the DrivingTestM.java it gives me an error with the line:

```
System.out.println( question.getDescription() );
```

Im not sure what the error may be. Can anyone try and shed some light on this error? Thanks!

Question.java:

```
public class Question {
String description;
String answerA;
String answerB;
String answerC;
int correctAnswer;
int answer;
Boolean answerCorrect;

public Question(){

}
public Question(String description, String answerA, String answerB, String answerC, int correctAnswer, int answer){
    this.description = description;
    this.answerA = answerA;
    this.answerB = answerB;
    this.answerC = answerC;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.answer = answer;

}
public Question(String description, String answerA, String answerB, String answerC, int correctAnswer){
    this.description = description;
    this.answerA = answerA;
    this.answerB = answerB;
    this.answerC = answerC;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}

public Boolean isAnswerCorrect() {
    return answerCorrect;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getAnswerA() {
    return answerA;
}
public void setAnswerA(String answerA) {
    this.answerA = answerA;
}
public String getAnswerB() {
    return answerB;
}
public void setAnswerB(String answerB) {
    this.answerB = answerB;
}
public String getAnswerC() {
    return answerC;
}
public void setAnswerC(String answerC) {
    this.answerC = answerC;
}
public int getCorrectAnswer() {
    return correctAnswer;
}
public void setCorrectAnswer(int correctAnswer) {
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}
public int getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}
public void setAnswer(int answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}
}
```

DrivingTest.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrivingTest {
int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
Question currentQuestion;
Boolean lastQuestion;
int score;
List<Question> q = new ArrayList<Question>();
Question quest = new Question();

public DrivingTest() throws FileNotFoundException{
    File f = new File("DrivingTest.txt");
    //int n = 1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String desc = sc.nextLine();
        String A =  sc.nextLine();
        String B =  sc.nextLine();
        String C =  sc.nextLine();
        String h =  sc.nextLine();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(h);
        String blank = sc.nextLine();
        q.add(new Question(desc, A,B,C,a) );
        }
        sc.close();
    }

public void setCurrentQuestionIndex(int currentQuestionIndex) {
    this.currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex;
}
public int getCurrentQuestionIndex() {
    return currentQuestionIndex;
}

public Boolean isLastQuestion() {
    if(currentQuestionIndex == q.size() - 1){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public Question getCurrentQuestion() {
    return currentQuestion;
}

public void setCurrentQuestion(Question currentQuestion) {
    this.currentQuestion = currentQuestion;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
}
```

DrivingTestM.java (the test file):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class DrivingTestMain {

public static void main( String args[] ) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    DrivingTest drivingTest = new DrivingTest();

    while( true )
    {
        // display the current question
        Question question = drivingTest.getCurrentQuestion();
        System.out.println( question.getDescription() );
        System.out.println( "\t" + question.getAnswerA() );
        System.out.println( "\t" + question.getAnswerB() );
        System.out.println( "\t" + question.getAnswerC() + "\n" );

        // set the answer to the current question to 1
        drivingTest.getCurrentQuestion().setAnswer( 1 );

        // if this is the last question, we are done.
        if( drivingTest.isLastQuestion() ) break;

        // it is not the last question, so increment CurrentQuestionIndex
        int currentQuestionIndex = drivingTest.getCurrentQuestionIndex();
        drivingTest.setCurrentQuestionIndex( currentQuestionIndex + 1 );
    }

    // display the test score
    System.out.println( "Your test score is: " + drivingTest.getScore() );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're not setting the current question anywhere before you are trying to use it.

you need a method like:

```
public void startTest()
{
    currentQuestion = q.get(0);
}
```

and then:

```
   DrivingTest drivingTest = new DrivingTest();
   drivingTest.startTest();

   while( true )
   {
   //....
```

also ensure you have questions to get, or you will get other errors as well..

if you are using eclipse, try Debugging your code by stepping through it...

you might want to look in a better way to terminate that loop as well, currently it will fail at the end of the test...

EDIT: ok the loop wont break, but its really messy...

Edit of the DrivingTest constructor:

```
public DrivingTest() throws FileNotFoundException{
File f = new File("DrivingTest.txt");
//int n = 1;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    String desc = sc.nextLine();
    String A =  sc.nextLine();
    String B =  sc.nextLine();
    String C =  sc.nextLine();
    String h =  sc.nextLine();
    int a = Integer.parseInt(h);
    String blank = sc.nextLine();
    q.add(new Question(desc, A,B,C,a) );
    }
    sc.close();

    //ensure it's 0.
    currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    //sets up your first question object.
    setCurrentQuestion( q.get(currentQuestionIndex) );
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. The only thing is I'm suppose to work with the DrivingTestM.java without altering it in any way.

Comment: ah ok, then at the end of your constructor the test has to be ready to be administered, i'll update my post with further comments

Answer (score 0):

You will get java.lang.NullPointerException because you store your Question object in Q list but you don't read objects from it. Try something like this in main class instead of:

```
Question question = drivingTest.getCurrentQuestion();
```

use

```
List<Question> qList = drivingTest.getQ();
Question question = qList.get(i);
```

also add Q getter in your DrivingTest class.

If you don't want modify main class than make changes in getCurrentQuestion() method:

```
int i = 0;
public Question getCurrentQuestion() {
    if (i<q.size()-1) 
         return q.get(i++);
    else return q.get(i);
}
```

.

Comment: I'm suppose to use the main class as it is and not alter it. So I'm trying to find a way to change my DrivingTest class.